# Django forloop in templates

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I want to show all my blog in database and the lastest post to the order so I try

```
{%for i in post%}
    {{post.title}}
    {{post.post_time|date:"Y/m/d"}}
    {{post.content}}
```

but I can't let the lastest one show on the top of the page

I know forloop.last can show lastest one but just did one time,

How to do with forloop ??

Comment: You mean `{{i.title}}` right?

Comment: Yes, it worked!!!
Thx for your answer

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please click the "checkmark" at the answer to accept it.

Comment: I cant vote because i dont have 15 reputation

Comment: I don't mean "vote", but accepting the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an ordering problem, try to order your result when you're querying, example: `MyModel.objects.order_by('myfield')` uses `-myfield` for descending order.

Comment: I got it !!thanks
but a little qusetion why to use -field not field ?
what the - means

Comment: the - means in descending order, if you don't add - it will be in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the ordering in your view.

```
# views.py
post = Post.objects.all().order_by('-post_time')
```

This will order your posts by date.